# Python - format and mapping a list with lambda - 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.6, python-2.x

Trying to format list so i can execute it in a query but getting a 'list' object has no attribute 'map' and sure why?
Using python 2.6
The list has string of names.

```
params = ",".join(flagged_job_names.map(lambda x: "?"))

cursor.execute(sql.format(params), flagged_job_names)
```

Answer (score 11):

`map` is a function, not a method of a list.

```
params = ",".join(map(lambda x: "?", flagged_job_names))
```

BTW, you can use list comprehension or generator expression instead of `map`:

```
params = ",".join("?" for x in flagged_job_names)
```

But for this specific case, following are also possible:

```
params = ",".join(["?"] * len(flagged_job_names))

params = ",".join("?" * len(flagged_job_names))
```

The last one is possible, because the string (`?`) is one-character.

Comment: Which one is faster b/c this list is huge!!

Comment: @user3590149, [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) them.

Comment: @user3590149, For example: http://ideone.com/6EmPy8 (Result will be different according to Python implementations, platform, ...)